# App corre en la web pero no en el dispositivo físico

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, apk

Cree una app con ionic 6, angular y capacitor y corre correctamente en la web cuando hago el ionic serve, ejecutó los comandos para agregar android y demás dependencias al proyecto y generar el apk y/o emularlo y el proceso se hace correcto, generar el apk y los instalo o también lo puedo emular pero cuando ingreso mi la credencial (usuario y contraseña) me arroja un error. Lo raro es que en en navegador eso no pasa y me permite ingresar al siguiente componente y hacer el resto de su lógica
imprimí el error y esto es lo que me arroja.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Habilita conexiones http en Android, o usa el plugin nativo http

Comment: eso ya lo hice en mi archivo manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

incluso por medio del npm instalé los cors